# How to install pdflatex in heroku

Tags: heroku, pandoc, pdflatex

I make a markdown to pdf converter by using flask. The conversion doesn't work, and an internal server error is shown.

In order to track it, I run `heroku logs` and get this error:

```
2018-05-04T03:38:26.134931+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pypandoc/__init__.py", line 325, in _convert_input
2018-05-04T03:38:26.134932+00:00 app[web.1]:     'Pandoc died with exitcode "%s" during conversion: %s' % (p.returncode, stderr)
2018-05-04T03:38:26.134942+00:00 app[web.1]: RuntimeError: Pandoc died with exitcode "47" during conversion: b'pdflatex not found. Please select a different --pdf-engine or install pdflatex\n'
```

This is make sense since I use pandoc to do the conversion.

To solve the error, I try to look for buildpack that support pdflatex. And unfortunately I cannot find any.

So, I try another possible solution, install pdflatex via `heroku run`.

```
gofrendi@asgard:~/Projects/markdown-to-moodle-xml$ heroku run apt-get install pdflatex
Running apt-get install pdflatex on ⬢ m2m-py... up, run.7496 (Free)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
E: Unable to locate package pdflatex
```

But probably I made mistake somewhere.

My question is: how can I install pdflatex on my heroku app?

Comment: The package is not called `pdflatex`, it's `sudo apt-get install texlive-full`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for custom buildpack - you can always define what packages to install on `heroku.yaml`, inside the `build - packages` directive:

```
build:
  packages:
    - texlive-latex-base
    - texlive-fonts-recommended
    - texlive-fonts-extra
    - texlive-latex-extra
```